# MongoDB how to rollback or destroy the newly created collection in transaction

Tags: database, mongodb, transactions

The problem I am trying to solve is in order to create collection `foo`, I need to add the user request data to `bar`. (If `bar` doesn't exist, create `bar`, else insert the data to `bar`.) Next, I want to pass `bar`'s objectID to `foo`'s field so that I can reference `bar` and create `foo`.

But if I first create `bar` success, then I try to create `foo` but it fails, I want to destroy the newly created `bar`. But, if `bar` exists before, then I only want to remove the added data from `bar`.

I tried to add these operations into a transaction, but MongoDB doesn't allow manipulating newly collection inside a transaction according the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session.startTransaction/):

> Within a transaction, you can only specify read and write (CRUD) operations on existing collections. For example, a multi-document transaction cannot include an insert operation that would result in the creation of a new collection.

What is a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Can you have `foo` and `bar` collections created first ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I should create the empty corrections `foo` and `bar` first, and it solves my problem.